# How to concatenate strings from multiple rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following columns:

- PRODUCT
- YEAR_UPDATED

Example data:

```
PROD1,2017
PROD1,2015
PROD2,2014
PROD3,2017
```

How can I get a list of when each product was updated?  Something like:

```
PRODUCT,2017,2016,2015,2014,etc
PROD1,Y,N,Y,N
PROD2,N,N,N,Y
PROD3,Y,N,N,N
```

or

```
PROD1,2017,2015
PROD2,2014
PROD3,2017
```

Oracle DB

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, interesting. What query did you try? Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Just to clarify, does it look like this at the beginning: `Prod1, 2017; Prod1, 2015; Prod2, 2014;` etc.?

Comment: RDBMS=Oracle; Yes the data matches your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming the table's name is `Products`, change it to whatever your table's name is.

**Oracle**

You achieve it by using the `LISTAGG` [function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030).

```
select p.Product || ', ' || listagg(p.YEARUPDATED,',') within group (order by p.YEARUPDATED)
from Products p
group by p.Product;
```

If you are using **SQL Server**, this is how you can do it.

```
select p.Product + ', ' + stuff((select ', '+ cast(tp.YearUpdated as varchar(4)) from Products tp where p.Product = tp.Product
          FOR XML PATH('')) , 1, 2, '')
from Products p
group by p.Product
```

In case you want to quickly test it, you can try this out (using an in-memory table).

```
declare @Products table (Product varchar(50), YearUpdated int);

insert into @Products values ('Product 1', 2000);
insert into @Products values ('Product 1', 2001);
insert into @Products values ('Product 1', 2002);
insert into @Products values ('Product 1', 2003);
insert into @Products values ('Product 2', 2010);
insert into @Products values ('Product 2', 2011);
insert into @Products values ('Product 4', 2012);
insert into @Products values ('Product 4', 2013);
insert into @Products values ('Product 4', 2015);
insert into @Products values ('Product 3', 2005);

select p.Product + ', ' + stuff((select ', '+ cast(tp.YearUpdated as varchar(4)) from @Products tp where p.Product = tp.Product
          FOR XML PATH('')) , 1, 2, '')
from @Products p
group by p.Product
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have id  and year columns in your table :

```
   select cast ( t1.id as  varchar) + ',' + ( case when  t1.rn2 = 1   then  '2015' else '' end )
+ 
   ( case when  t1.rn2 = 2  then  '2015,2016 ' else  '' end ) + 
   ( case when  t1.rn2 =  3 then  '2015,2016,2017' else '' end ) 
 from 
  (select distinct  yourTBL.id , max(yourTBL.rn)
   over ( partition by yourTBL.id order by yourTBL.year rows BETWEEN  UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
        AND UNBOUNDED following ) as rn2
 from (select id ,  year ,  
      row_number()over (partition by id order by year) as rn from yourTBL ) t) t1
```

Comment: You gotta be kidding us. Why are you hard-coding the string? What if the table has 2000 records with years starting at 1950 through 1999? Also, no Id in the table, the question is clearly stating the columns of the table (PRODUCT and YEAR_UPDATED).